Problem with replace directive in Go module after forking GitHub repository
We recently forked a no longer maintained GitHub repository, "github.com/user/project/v10" (pseudoname), into a private Bitbucket repository, "bitbucket.org/xyz-code/forked-project/v10", where we applied a bug fix.
In another Go project, we are replacing the contents of this forked module using the replace directive:
module bitbucket.org/xyz-code/operator

go 1.21

replace (
    github.com/user/project/v10 v10.2.1 => bitbucket.org/xyz-code/forked-project/v10 v10.2.2-rc.1
)

require github.com/user/project/v10 v10.2.1

Additionally, the project imports types from the original module as follows:
package model

import (
    "github.com/user/project/v10/types"
)

When running go mod tidy, we encounter the following error:
go mod tidy                                                 
go: finding module for package bitbucket.org/xyz-code/forked-project/v10/types
go: found bitbucket.org/forked-project-code/v10/types in bitbucket.org/xyz-code/user/project/v10 v10.2.2-rc.1
go: bitbucket.org/xyz-code/forked-project/v10@v10.2.2-rc.1 used for two different module paths (bitbucket.org/xyz-code/forked-project/v10 and github.com/user/project/v10)

Running go clean -modcache did not resolve the issue.
How can we resolve this conflict so that the forked version is used consistently throughout the project?

"How can we resolve this conflict so that the forked version is used consistently throughout the project?" You cannot. You cannot "fork" (in the "github sense") a Go module (at least not in in the general case). You'r fork has to become a standalone, new module and you must adjust all import path to the new module.

"replace directives only apply in the main module’s go.mod file and are ignored in other modules."

The trick was to rename only the module name in the go.mod file of the forked repository, and not the import statements, which is typically done automatically during rename refactoring in IDEs.
